# Injecting new field to riemann event

Tags: clojure, riemann

I'm probably not understanding some key concepts in riemann/clojure.
I'm trying to parse field :service from event which is in format `"aaa:1234.bbbb.cccc.ddddd"`, and add new field pid to the event using function "with".
Anybody can explain to me why this code in `riemann.config` is throwing exception:

```
...
(let [index (default :ttl 300 (update-index (index)))]

 ; Inbound events will be passed to these streams:
 (streams
 index
 (where (service #"(\w+):(\d+)\.(\w+)\.(\w+)\.(\w+)")
   (with :pid (str/replace service #"(\w+):(\d+)\.(\w+)\.(\w+)\.(\w+)" "$2")
)
)
...

user=> (riemann.bin/reload!)
#error {
 :cause "Unable to resolve symbol: service in this context"
 :via
 [{:type clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException
 :message "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: service in this context, compiling:(/etc/riemann/riemann.config:73:19)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `(where (service ,,,))` is just syntactic sugar by the `where` macro for `(where* (fn [event] (let [service (:service event)] ,,,)))`, which is why you can't use `service` in the body of `where`: it is not a defined name there.

Looking at the [documentation](http://riemann.io/api.html) for with, it seems to me you should use `smap`:

```
(where (service #"(\w+):(\d+)\.(\w+)\.(\w+)\.(\w+)")
   (smap (fn [e] (assoc e :pid (str/replace (:service e) #"(\w+):(\d+)\.(\w+)\.(\w+)\.(\w+)" "$2")))))
```

Comment: @user8173324 cool! Please accept the answer then, so that people know this question is solved :)